# Flat Text File Parsing

Tags: java, parsing

I have a rather complex flat file that I need to parse in Java, but I can't find any libraries that fit my needs.

Essentially, I have a file consisting of a single line of the format:
    [num num num num]
Example: [0.1 0.2 15 30]

This is followed by series of two-field CSV formatted lines:
    num, num
Example: 1.0000E+01, 5.7104E-02

This pattern is repeated, so the file consists of blocks that include a header and some data. Here's an example of a whole file (truncated to only three blocks): http://pastebin.com/q3VfRtmF

I need to convert that file into an array of "FluxSet" objects, as defined here: http://pastebin.com/knUFQuVY

A Pair is defined here: http://pastebin.com/s5Ehqpab

Does anyone know of a library applicable to this kind of parsing?

Thanks,
taktoa

Answer (score 1):

If your input file so well defined, then go and write a simple file reader that would read the file line by line and do simple `String.split()` and `Integer.parseInt()` or any other method as applicable, and finally populate the required object with the data you just parsed.

Comment: I tried that solution previously, but it got complicated fast, and never really worked.

Comment: @taktoa If it got too complicated, perhaps you are looking at the problem from the wrong perspective? You shouldn't really need much more than a couple of nested `for` loops, reading lines.

Comment: java.util.Scanner should help a bit, too.

Comment: @taktoa Post your code with the problems you are getting, that you have tried, and we could try to simplify it.

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://hpaste.org/73113
The parseFile function gave me constant problems (mostly indexOutOfBounds exceptions but others as well, and debugging the code became a time-consuming task)